# Get the ID of firebase document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I have this collection:

```
//console.log(currentUserUID)


   await fire
       .firestore()
       .collection('userEventsCal')
       .doc(currentUserUID)
       .collection(eventID)
       .get()
```

I am calling this in a new page, so I don't have access to the eventID. I am trying to figure out how to do it with just

```
await fire
           .firestore()
           .collection('userEventsCal')
           .doc(currentUserUID)
```

but it's failing. Is my logic wrong or is this just impossible to do?

```
 await fire
       .firestore()
       .collection('userEventsCal')
       .doc(currentUserUID)
       .get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Doc data lol:", doc.data());
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

It looks like this in firebase:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of your Firestore structure? Generally it's a good idea to keep collection names statics. For example, `users -> {userId} -> events -> {eventId}` where events is the sub-collection name would have been a better structure. Also what's the use case here? Are you like trying to query events of a user or so?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Hi, I have added screenshots and yeah I am trying to query the user events. do you mean to change .doc({userID}) is it? Thank you!:)

Comment: If `eventId` is a collection, what documents do you store in that? As mentioned in my previous comment, if you create a sub-collection "events" and store each event as a document then you can easily query a user's events by `db.collection(\`users/${userId}\events\`).get()`

Comment: you can pass the eventID in the link so you can access it in the new page or use a state in the parent component, in one page you setState(eventID) in the other page you use the state, how else you know which collection to get if you don't have an id. Else you can "set" the id but make sure its unic in the document, eg:  collection("users").doc(userUid).collection("blogs") [https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to list the subcollections of the document with the `DocumentReference` corresponding to `firestore().collection('userEventsCal').doc(currentUserUID)`.

As a matter of fact, retrieving a list of collections **is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries**, as explained in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

I wrote an article which proposes solutions to this problem: [How to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166).

Basically, you can either save the list in a dedicated field of the parent document or use a Cloud Function.

At first glance it seems the first approach is probably the most interesting one in your case. Note however the 1MB limit for a document.

Comment: Hello @emilysmyth, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?